# Powershell script to replace strings with filename

Tags: powershell, filenames, file-rename

How do I write the filename (basename and not the fullname) into the same file by replacing a string present in the file.
Basically, I have a bunch of .psf files inside a folder called C:\Downloads\PreValidation.

1. I want to change each file to a .csv format and
2. while doing so I want to replace the string called 'Space Planning Project' present
   inside one of the records of the file with the filename without the
   extension.

This is the script that I am trying to run -

```
foreach($file in (dir C:\Downloads\PreValidation\*.psf)){
$fromdir = "C:\Downloads\Prevalidation\*.psf"
$fullname = gi $fromdir| select fullname
$b = $fullname[0]
$b.fullname
Copy-Item $file.fullname C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv
Get-Content C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.replace("Space Planning Project","$b.fullname")} | Set-Content C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv 
}
```

but its erroring out saying

```
 Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv' because it  does not exist.
 At C:\cap_sps\powershell\testfilename.ps1:7 char:12
 + Get-Content <<<<  C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv | ForEach-Object  {$_.replace("Space Planning Project","$b.fullname")} | Set-Content C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotF
oundException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

Note that I am using my final psaload.csv to load into an Oracle database and in the last step of my script I am removing this file so that I can run the same commands in loop for the rest of the .psf files present in the above folder.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
Sanders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of redundancy in your code, with the `dir` in the loop and then using the file to get the item again. Also you are copying to the same csv file for each of the psf files and the copy line mentions a file `psaload1.csv`, but you are trying to get the content of `psaload.csv`, causing the error that you see.

Try something like this ( I am making some assumptions here and untested):

```
gci C:\Downloads\PreValidation\*.psf | %{
$file = $_
gc $file.fullname | % {$_ -replace "Space Planning Project",$file.BaseName } | Set-Content "C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\$($file.BaseName).csv"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manoj - this is working like a charm. Since my sqlloader is expecting to load a file with name psaload.csv, I just changed the filename in the Set-Content as psaload.csv. here is my code based on yours -       gci C:\Downloads\PreValidation\*.psf | %{
$file = $_
gc $file.fullname | % {$_ -replace "Space Planning Project",$file.BaseName } | Set-Content "C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv"
cmd.exe /k C:\CAP_SPS\Batchscripts\runfixloader.bat
   
Remove-item C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv

}

Answer (score 0):

To get the BaseName of a file object , use the BaseName property. You can modify your script like so:

```
$files = gi $fromdir| select fullname,basename
$fullname = $files[0].fullname
$b = $files[0].basename
```

As for the error message, you are trying to retrieve the contents of a file that does not exist. Your copy line

```
Copy-Item $file.fullname C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv
```

has a "1" in the file name, but in the next line, your filename to Get-Content does not.

Comment: Thanks for your response zdan. But I am getting the following error now -  Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At C:\cap_sps\powershell\testfilename.ps1:7 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  $files.$fullname C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv' because it does not exist.

Comment: Contd. from previous comment - + Get-Content <<<<  C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.replace("Space Planning Project","$b"
)} | Set-Content C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv:String) [Get-Content], ItemNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand.           Adding my code in the below comment -

Comment: foreach($file in (dir C:\Downloads\PreValidation\*.psf)){
$fromdir = "C:\Downloads\Prevalidation\*.psf"
$files = gi $fromdir| select fullname,basename
$fullname = $files[0].fullname
$b = $files[0].basename
Copy-Item $files.$fullname C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv
Get-Content C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv | ForEach-Object {$_.replace("Space Planning Project","$b")} | Set-Content C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv 
cmd.exe /k C:\CAP_SPS\Batchscripts\runfixloader.bat
Remove-item C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv
Remove-Item C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload1.csv

Comment: @user982201: try manojlds answer, it should do what you're looking for.